# Read wave file in matlab

Tags: matlab

this is the code and i have no idea why it's not workinng

> > y=audioread('Arabic_Male_Alain_G_Corp');
> >     Error using audioread (line 74)
> >     The filename specified was not found in the MATLAB path.

Answer (score 0):

Is this file located in your active folder? If not, you need to specify the full filepath (e.g. `C:\...`)